# How to find when a User Object in Azure AD was last changed/modified?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

OnPremise Active Directory AD seems to have whenChanged field by whihc the latest changes can be found. How to do the same in Azure AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure AD Graph API also provide **Differential query** which returns all changes made to specified entities during the time between two consecutive requests. For example, if you make a differential query request an hour after the previous differential query request, only the changes made during that hour will be returned. This functionality is especially useful when synchronizing tenant directory data with an application’s data store.

More detail about it you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-differential-query).

Comment: What is the difference between "odata.nextLink" and "aad.nextLink"? Is that relevant to this topic? 
As in, would the response contain "odata.nextLink" - which is used for paging results - when a differential query is made? Or is that same funcitionality addressed by "aad.nextLink"?

Comment: It is a little different with paging results. In the differential query, we using the `aad.nextLink` to check more changing results. You can also check this [bolg](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2013/04/08/differential-query-in-windows-azure-active-directory-graph/).

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment.

If you're updating a user via the API, you'll have to keep track of these manually (in a SQL DB for example). If you're relying on the Microsoft hosted policies, then you just won't know.

See the user entity reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity